# jquery check if radiobox is checked on price calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have this piece of JavaScript that will sum up a totalprice based on radio/checkbox selection

**JQUERY**

```
var price = 0;
$('.price-input').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        price += parseInt($(this).attr("data-price"), 10);
        $('.total-price').text(price);
        $('.total-price-input').val(price);
    } else {
        price -= parseInt($(this).attr("data-price"), 10);
        $('.total-price').text(price);
        $('.total-price-input').val(price);
    }
});
```

The HTML is a collection of 3 radiobuttons and 3 checkboxes, where the radiobutton is one price and the checkboxes can sum up 3 prices with the radiobutton price to give a total price.

```
<input class="price-input" data-price="2000" id="ChosenLane" name="ChosenLane" type="radio" value="Konference - Spor 1: Lean">                         
<input class="price-input" data-price="1300" id="ChosenLane" name="ChosenLane" type="radio" value="Konference - Spor 2: Innovation">                          
<input class="price-input" data-price="1600" id="ChosenLane" name="ChosenLane" type="radio" value="Kage">

<input type="checkbox" name="lanes" value="Aften buffet" data-price="1000" class="price-input">      
<input type="checkbox" name="lanes" value="fthrctfyh" data-price="5456" class="price-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="lanes" value="dfhxfhg" data-price="54545" class="price-input">
```

All in all this works - if I select a radiobutton it will add the radiobutton price to the price, but if I click a radiobutton again it will add the price again to the totalprice. I want the radiobuttons, not to add if one is selected, but instead just use its price.

So if I check a radiobutton it will at 2000 to the price and if I click another radiobutton, it will subtract the 2000 and add 1300 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following solution:

**JQUERY**

```
$(function () {
    $('.price-input').change(function () {
        var price = 0;
        $('.price-input').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
             price += parseInt($(this).attr("data-price"), 10);
            }
        })
        $(".totalPrice").text(price);
    });
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkqqfaqv/

Comment: Arh... Nice and simple solution! Works perfectly! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to change event from click event. As click event is called every time user clicks the radio box, doesn't matter whether selected or not. Change event will be triggered if the state of checkbox changes

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear about your relation betweeen price and total-price-input.

As a general rule for much higher robustness: Don't rely on clean unsetting-setting, i.e. that substracting X and adding Y always match up one on one.

**Rather:**

- always start your callback function with `price=0`
- check which input buttons and radio button are set
- add up accordingly

This has also the benefit, that you can trigger such a clean-from-start calback after page DOM load: I.e. if user goes browser-forward, then back, inputs and radio buttons keep being checked (in any modern browser) ➠ having the correct value for that resurrected choice (rather than 0 and a “refresh problem” is good. ➠ Thus put it in a named distinct function, to call upon `$.ready()` and upon `.change()`.

Also, I'd use [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) rather than .click(): Input can possibly change state by other means than click (like keyboard navigation?), and change is what you are looking for.